# Sinatra and "controllers" behaviour

Tags: sinatra, rack

Sinatra from Box does't allow separate action to file? Like this:

```
index.php
  get '/' and other

user.php
 get '/user/show/'
 post '/user/new/' and other
```

How to say sinatra use user.php for '/user/*' request, and index.php for '/'.
And how looks application with many get post in one file written in sinatra? (one huge ass?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a lot, exist some solution:

1.

```
class Get < Sinatra::Base
 get('/') { 'GET!' }
end
class Post < Sinatra::Base
 post('/') { 'POST!' }
end

class Routes < Sinatra::Base
 get('/') { Get.call(env) }
 post('/') { Post.call(env) }
end

run Routes
```

2.

```
class Foo < Sinatra::Base
 get('/foo') { 'foo' }
end

class Bar < Sinatra::Base
 get('/bar') { 'bar' }
end

Routes = Rack::Mount::RouteSet.new do |set|
 set.add_route Foo, :path_info => %r{^/foo$}
 set.add_route Bar, :path_info => %r{^/bar$}
end

run Routes
```